# Telethon on google colab pro plus

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, python-asyncio

I am trying to run telethon code on google colab plus and leave it running background. The code is running fine and has no errors while that is started and running in the browser tab. When I close the tab and reopened it, It showed too many repeated errors in the output console as below

```
RuntimeError: cannot enter context: <Context object at 0x7f0063bc04b0> is already entered
Exception in callback BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(18, 1)
handle: <Handle BaseAsyncIOLoop._handle_events(18, 1)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

[image]

The code I am running on colab pro plus notebook

```
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events, Button
from telethon.sessions import StringSession
from telethon import functions, types
import asyncio
import nest_asyncio
nest_asyncio.apply()


api_id = 
api_hash = ''
session=''
async def main():

  async with TelegramClient(StringSession(session), api_id, api_hash) as client:
    print("Inside")
    @client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=[xxxxxxxxxx]))
    async def my_event_handler(event):
      print(event.raw_text)
    
    while True:
      #doSomething and wait for 0.03 seconds
      await asyncio.sleep(0.03)
    
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I am unable to understand what caused the error because the errors are only showing up when I closed and reopened the notebook where the code is running

Answer (score 0):

The issue got solved after installing this package

```
pip install --upgrade ipykernel
```

Source : https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_console/issues/163#issuecomment-413468124